# Enable Memcached on App Engine runtime PHP 7.2

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm trying since several days to enable session storage in memcache on Google App Engine, using the Symfony framework. Application starts well, Memcached instance exists, but I always end up with sessions that are not stored (CSRF on all forms, etc).

So I've created a very simple POC to check if Memcached is working, and it actually doesn't.

Here's the POC code:

<kbd>app.yaml</kbd>

```
runtime: php72

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

<kbd>php.ini</kbd>

```
extension=memcached.so
```

<kbd>index.php</kbd>

```
<?php

$test = new \Memcached;
var_dump( $test->add('test', '42') );
echo 'value of test is: ', $test->get('test');
```

Result of the following code is:

> bool(false)
>   value of test is:

Memcache looks pretty well integrated to App Engine, so I'm wondering why I can't hit it.

---

Debugging Memcached, the error is the following:

> (0x75b27c3c040) NO SERVERS DEFINED -> libmemcached/initialize_query.cc:58

Any idea how to configure it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memcache is not supported in php72, you have to use php55 in case you need to access memcache

Comment: Ah. Ok I wasn't expecting such an answer  I'm currently running a Symfony4 application and it's just not an acceptable solution. If I store my session in temp directory (which is writeable), do you know if load balancers will be sticky to the same instance?

Comment: I don't think so. How about cloud memorystore?

Comment: Well, I'll look at that, thank you for the advices 